# React Native Reanimated 2 - useSharedValue is not a funtion

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I emigrated from Reanimated 1 to Reanimated 2. When I am trying to run the example code given in the playground repo -in the installation guide, I get this error:

[Error given in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXW7.png)

Link to repo/code: https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground/blob/master/App.js

Comment: did you manage to solve this? Getting the same error...

Comment: Unfortunaly not. Ended up deleting the branch and using Reanimated v1... Waiting for someone to figure out a solution.